# Apache Thrift and multiple handlers/processors

Tags: c++, thrift

I've a C++ application with multiple classes and I should make available their methods over a Thrift service using the same port.

Actually, according with documentation, the only way seems to create a single class using thrift generator that call other class methods.

Instead, I would like to directly use native class methods. Is it possible to create a service that supports multiple handlers/processors?  Or multiple services on the same port?

P.S. I'm pretty new to Thrift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service multiplexing is implemented since 0.9.1.  Look here for details and samples: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-563

Here's a link on related question: [I'd like to use multiple services on one transport ( Thrift )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905737/id-like-to-use-multiple-services-on-one-transport-thrift/9083686#9083686)

Comment: thank you! it's exactly what i needed . i downloaded thrift few days ago and it was still at 1.9.0 :)